# How to publish a post to Facebook respecting MVC pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to develop a script that every hour publish a news update (fetched from my database) to a Facebook Fanpage.

I have put this in a controller, but I have often need to use "Rails routes", "Helper methos" and other things.
So if I want to respect all MVP pattern, and keep things clean, how should I structure all of this?

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_access_token)


  @news.each do |n|

    res = @graph.put_connections("PAGE_ID", "feed", {
      :message => "Here I need to use an helper method",
      :link    => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.news_url(n, :host => 'server.com'),
      :picture => "Another helper method"
    })

    puts res
    end

  render :text => "Ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all context with Facebook in model. Models not necessarily need has `ActiveRecord::Base` , so you could create a file called facebook_handler.rb

gets me, when I saw `class` with behavior like models, but programmers putting into lib path. IMO what you need it's create own class and handler with parameters that you need.

Maybe you can do inheritance with `Koala::Facebook::API`.

Comment: Ok, but in a model can I use resource_path and helpers methods?

Comment: What is the problem in use it? Obviously you'll create a dependency with Rails, but you still need it. So you may create a private method and use it with Rails Helper.